# Maya mirroring normal flipped

Tags: maya, mirroring

I have a half poly mesh and went to `edit` `duplicate special` and selected instance and scaled in -1,1,1 to mirror it on the x-axis. However the mirrored object has flipped normals, in perspective the mirrored object is black and it turns normal when I reverse the normals (but then of course the original side has bad normals :()

Essentially I would like to have something like the Blender mirror modifier working so I can model one side of the model and see it reflected as a whole. Is there a better way to do this or can I somehow fix the normal issue so I don't have half a black model?

Comment: I can't tell if this is even a programming question, or just general Maya. If general Maya, Stack Overflow isn't the right site for that. If programming, this is too broad without you showing your existing code and the where specifically you got stuck.

Comment: In future, Try this kind of question on CGTalk or Tech-artists.org. In this specific case you want **Mesh >> Mirror Geometry**, not duplicate and negative scales which always flips normals.

Comment: @thedox thanks but that does not make the changes appear on the mirrored side. I'll ask in GCTalk.